# Request for <HTTP level caching> explanation

Tags: http, caching

Excerpt from Flight PHP micro framework website:

> **HTTP Caching**
>
> Flight provides built-in support for HTTP level caching.
>   If the caching condition is met, Flight will return an HTTP 304 Not
>   Modified response. The next time the client requests the same
>   resource, they will be prompted to use their locally cached version

I managed to install the framework and began to harness it.

Being a PHP n00b, any explanation on `HTTP level caching` is welcome. An expansion on the `caching condition` would be also great.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: It means HTTP-level caching, i.e. caching at the HTTP level, probably the `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, `If-Modified-Since`, etc. headers.

Comment: Does this mean that caching take place on the client side (browser) ?

Comment: Browser, organizational caches, proxy servers, front-end caches, etc.

Comment: Ok, so I presume `caching condition` has mainly to do with configuration of all those stuffs, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"HTTP level caching" simply means "HTTP-level caching", i.e. caching done through HTTP headers (e.g. `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, `If-Modified-Since`). These headers can be set by either servers or clients.

Clients can set a cache condition like `If-Modified-Since` to get updated content only when their cached copy expires. The server sees `If-Modified-Since` and compares the client's date to the date on the resource; if the resource is newer, it is served up. Otherwise, the server returns a small `304 Not Modified` response to inform the client that nothing has changed since their last request.